# unable to browse asp.net mvc 4 page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm not sure what I did, and this just happened today.

I am unable to browse one of my `MVC 4` applications, which I was previously able to do.

There's no error message.

When I right click on my project and view in browser, it just shows `"Connecting..." - localhost:55223,` and it remains there like forever.

I have tried the following:

```
1) Copied the proejct onto another PC and browse - works!
2) Create a new MVC application in visual studio and browse - works!
```

I have set a breakpoint in `global.asax's` start method, and it doesn't even get there.

What else do I have to check?

Please help

Comment: seems like your MVC4 installation got corrupt, try reinstalling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried right clicking on the IIS icon in you taskbar and exiting it? Then build the project again to restart IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cannot comment because i am unable to see comment button.

See your global.asax RegisterRoutes method is it fine? for example:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GridPaging",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
```